# Obtener un valor de un conjunto de filas en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo una tabla en Excel que representa los pedidos de compra. Ej:

```
pedido | linea ped. | estado línea   
-----------------------------------
1      | 1          | Cumplido     
1      | 2          | En progreso  
2      | 1          | Cumplido
```

Y necesito agregar una columna que se calcule automáticamente, a través de fórmulas, el estado del pedido:

```
pedido | línea ped. | estado línea | estado pedido
-------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1          | Cumplido     | En progreso
1      | 2          | En progreso  | En progreso
2      | 3          | Cumplido     | Cumplido
```

En el caso de ejemplo, el pedido **1** tiene los estados **Cumplido** y **En progreso** (para los las líneas 1 y 2 respectivamente). Dicho de otra forma, una parte del pedido llegó y la otra no. Necesito que la columna estado de pedido condense esa información y me diga que aún está **En progreso** (ya que uno de los materiales aún no llegó. En el caso del pedido **2**, sólo tiene una línea (un material), que ya fue Cumplido, por lo que el estado de todo el pedido fue cumplido.

Cuando la línea **2** del pedido **1** llegue, pondré que está **Cumplido** y, en ese caso, el estado del pedido completo debe pasar a **Cumplido** (ya que ambas líneas ya están cumplidas).

Idealmente me gustaría poder agregar la columna en la misma tabla, pero si no se puede, podría ser en otra aparte.

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es que se calcule automáticamente el valor de la columna [estado por código] usando las fórmulas de excel? Es decir, A = "En progreso" y B = "Cumplido"

Comment: No entiendo bien como formas la ultima columna. Puedes explicarlo mejor? Saludos

Comment: He dado por hecho @malvarez que necesitabas devolver en la columna una de las dos condiciones, te he añadido mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es seleccionar la columna estado línea de todos los que tienen el mismo número de pedido, y poner En Progreso si alguno de esos estados no es Cumplido, o Cumplido si todos lo son? No creo que eso pueda hacerse con funciones de Excel, me parece más bien para una función en VB, que puedes incluir como macro.

Comment: Exactamente @CarlosE.Ferro, eso mismo! Acabo de publicar una respuesta en este mismo post, pero no puedo darla por aceptada hasta que pasen 2 días. Eso solucionó el problema y es más sencillo de lo que pensaba! Gracias igual!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejo la respuesta acá de la [ayuda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42369697/7557396) que me brindaron en StackOverflow en ingles:

Hay que usar CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO junto con SI:

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(A:A,A2,C:C,"En progreso"),"En progreso","Cumplido")
```

Siendo A la columna con los pedidos y C con los estados de las líneas de pedido.

Si hay más estados, como es mi caso, sólo es cuestión de anidar los SI.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que suelo hacer yo es crearme una hoja con los valores a modo de maestro. Es decir, tu tendrías una hoja con los datos de este tipo:

```
código | estado  
---------------------
A      | En progreso
B      | Cumplido
```

Luego solo tienes que buscar en la hoja donde quieras mostrar el valor correspondiente. Por ejemplo, así: `=BUSCAR(A1;Hoja2!A:A;Hoja2!B:B)`

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Evidentemente mi consulta no fue nada clara. Me disculpo por eso. Ahí la corregí. Si aún no es clara, por favor avisame y la ajusto nuevamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay problema, lo entendí bien.

Answer (score 0):

Con esta formula te servirá.

```
=SI(A1="A";"En progreso";"Cumplido")
```

Solo tienes que sustituir el `A1` por tu columna y usar la fórmula en las celdas que quieras que te aparezca el valor.

Comment: Evidentemente mi consulta no fue nada clara. Me disculpo por eso. Ahí la corregí. Si aún no es clara, por favor avisame y la ajusto nuevamente. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usando las fórmulas `SI`.

Ejemplo de uso de la fórmula SI

```
=SI(A1="A";"En progreso";"Cumplido")
```

La función SI funciona con los siguientes parámetros:

> SI (prueba lógica;valor verdadero; valor falso)

**prueba lógica**: Es el campo a evaluar. Tendrás que igualarlo a lo que consideres que debe ser verdadero o falso, en este caso igual a "A". Si fuese tipo número va sin comillas.

**valor verdadero**: es lo que devolverá la función si se cumple la condición.

**valor falso**: es lo devolverá la función si no se cumple la condición.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @David, disculpame la demora, pero estaba reescribiendo la consulta con la esperanza de que resultara más clara. No sería esto lo que estoy necesitando, si ahora no se entiende con la nueva edición, por favor avisame y la sigo ajustando. Muchas gracias!